# Using an entity's custom field with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, ios7

I am trying to add a custom field to an entity, so I can create a predicate with that field when fetching objects with NSFetchedResultsController. The field is full_name:

```
@dynamic first_name;
@dynamic last_name;

@dynamic full_name;

-(NSString *)full_name {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"full_name"];
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.first_name, self.last_name];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"full_name"];
    return name;
}
```

Then, using NSFetchedResultsController, I am trying to fetch matched objects by full_name:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"full_name" ascending:YES]];

NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contact_full_name contains == '%@' ", trimmedSearchString]];

filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:filterPredicate];
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest                                                                                     managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

However, the query always returns empty results, even though the queried full name exists in the datastore. Any ideas why the predicate doesn't return valid results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your predicate uses "contact_full_name", not "full_name".
- `"… contains == '%@'"` should be `"… contains %@"` in the predicate.
- A Core Data fetch request can only filter and sort on *persistent* properties, not on transient or Objective-C based custom properties.

Comment: (1) and (2) are a result of a bad copy paste, sorry! 
So unless I store a full_name along the first_name and last_name (which will result an extra storage consumption) , I'll have to build a predicate based on a combination of first_name and last_name...

Comment: @Joel: Yes, exactly. To be precise, that is an restriction of the SQLite store. (There is a section about store-specific restrictions somewhere in the Core Data programming guide.)